# NHiberante Linq with named query

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-sql

I have a data consumer that expects to receive a IQueryable<> interface, and I need to reach my database through a complex native query, so a "named query".

Is possible to access named queries via NHibernate Linq interface ?

Comment: Maybe yes, in the future I can have also this situation, to get the result of a procedure as an IQueryable, but now no, I have only a complex native query difficult to reach using pure-Linq, and maybe NHiberante cannot build a correct query with its reduced support to Linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

Linq is a higher level than HQL and SQL, so you can't magically convert SQL to an IQueryable expression tree.